# Null POJO in @FormParam

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am developing RESTful services with Jersey and I have had a few problems since I updated the version from 2.6 to the latest.

I have a @BeanParam object containing @formParam parameters :

```
public class UpdateBeanParam {

    @FormParam
    private Area area;

    ...
}
```

When I submit a POST request (url-form-encoded) without defining an area parameter, I get a BadRequestException, caused by a NullPointerException in the default converter. With the old version it used to create an UpdateBeanParam with a null area.
This problem does not occur with String types (or other common types) as converters for those handle null values well.

Anyone knows how to allow null values for custom objects ?

Thanks for your help !